# Seaborn countplot not displaying correct frequncies

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a simple count plot using Seaborn of the frequencies of 3 different categories. The plot I am being given has completely incorrect count.

I am using the correct count plot method

```
sns.countplot(data = r.reset_index(), x = 'cat')
```

gives me [image: bad graph]

This is the DataFrame I'm trying to plot :

```
    count
high    38
low 64
medium  30
```

I want the graph to display the correct counts for each category, high medium and low

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `countplot` is going to count each occurrence of your `x` variable -- in this case, one observation per level.

From the API page for [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

> Show the counts of observations in each categorical bin using bars.
>
> A count plot can be thought of as a histogram across a categorical,
>   instead of quantitative, variable. The basic API and options are
>   identical to those for barplot(), so you can compare counts across
>   nested variables.

You want a simple `barplot`:

```
sns.barplot(data=df.reset_index(), x='index', y='count')
```

[image]